# Composer - files autoload - não funciona

Tags: composer, autoload

Meu código no composer.json está assim

```
{
    "name": "testesocial/vinicius",
    "description": "Login com facebook",
    "type": "project",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Source\\": "testeoauth/"
        },
        "files": [
            "source/Config.php"
        ]
    },
    "require": {
        "league/oauth2-facebook": "^2.0.*"
    }
}
```

meu source->config.php está assim:

```
define("FACEBOOK", [
    "app_id" => "",
    "app_secret" => "",
    "app_redirect" => "https://www.localhost/testeoauth/",
    "app_version" => "v4.0"
]);
```

Eu gostária de deixar esse arquivo com o array FACEBOOK no autolood, porém ele não está ficando, então estou tendo de dar require sempre, assim:

```
<?php
ob_start();

require "vendor/autoload.php";
// require "source/Config.php";

if(empty($_SESSION["userLogin"])) {    
    echo "<h1>Guest</h1>";

    $facebook = new \League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Facebook([
    'clientId'                => FACEBOOK["app_id"],
    'clientSecret'            => FACEBOOK["app_secret"],
    'redirectUri'             => FACEBOOK["app_redirect"],
    'graphApiVersion'         => FACEBOOK["app_version"]
]);

$authUrl = $facebook->getAuthorizationUrl([
    "scope" => ["email"]
]);

echo "<a title='FB Login' href='{$authUrl}'>Facebook Login</a>";

} else {
    echo "<h1>User Name</h1>";
}

ob_end_flush();
```

Eu queria não precisar dar o required

Comment: `require "vendor/autoload.php";` se fala nessa linha ???

Comment: Não, a linha que está comentada a "require "source/Config.php" Sem ela o meu código quebra.

Comment: Eu preciso saber então o conjunto de pastas, se tem o github disso?

Comment: Tenho não, eu tenho o zip dele.

Comment: possa ser que funcione mas, não do jeito que você fez, e outra precisa colocar no packgist isso ai no gerenciador de pacotes

Comment: Aqui o link para o github: https://github.com/sahusa/testeoauth

Comment: Rapaz é o outro link! se ta meio perdido.

Comment: Eu te mandei o link para o repositório do github do meu projeto

Comment: No repositório do GitHub só tem os arquivos do composer e o `index.php`, falta o resto. Revise os nomes dos arquivos e pastas, pode ser um erro de digitação

Comment: Mas o projeto realmente só contém esses arquivos atualmente, estou apenas testando o uso do composer, já consegui encontrar a solução, grato.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema pessoal. Apenas precisava carregar o autoload, para isso é necessário executar o comando 'composer dumpautoload' e pronto. Agradeço a quem tentou me ajudar de alguma forma.